# ISA Server, publishing a wildcard site

Tags: isaserver

We have a wildcard dns mapping at our DNS server, where all requests to *.A.com are redirected to our ISA Server.
We need to redirect all requests to an internal website http://10.10.10.10. We also need to keep the host-header intact so that we can rewrite urls on the web server. 
Is this possible with ISA?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's possible.

Set the Listner up to listen to everything on port 80.

In the Public name tab set *.A.com.

In the To tab set IP address to 10.10.10.10

Also, ensure the Forward the original host header instead of the actual one, checkbox is checked.